# Thread safety issues of SpscArrayQueue

Tags: java, multithreading

In a single producer and single consumer scenario, is this `queue` thread-safe?

1. `takeIndex` and `putIndex` need to be `AtomicLong`?
2. `Object[] ar` need to be `AtomicReferenceArray` so we can use `AtomicReferenceArray#set` to update `array`.

My understanding is that `Object[] arr` needs to be an `AtomicReferenceArray` to ensure visibility, so that when the `producer` puts an element, the consumer can see it immediately. Otherwise, when there is already an element in the array, maybe the `consumer` cannot consume it immediately (it may take the next `poll` to get the data), this will cause data consume delay?  But it will not bring abnormal behavior, such as consume the same element twice, or throw some unexpected exceptions (These are unacceptable).

```
public class SpscArrayQueue<E> implements Queue<E> {

    private final int cap;
    private Object[] arr; // change to AtomicReferenceArray?
    long takeIndex;  // change to AtomicLong?
    long putIndex;   // change to AtomicLong?
    final int mask;

    static int ceilingNextPowerOfTwo(int x) {
        return 1 << (Integer.SIZE - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(x - 1));
    }

    public SpscArrayQueue(int cap) {
        this.cap = ceilingNextPowerOfTwo(cap);
        arr = new Object[this.cap];
        mask = this.cap - 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean offer(E e) {
        if (null == e) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Null element");
        }
        final long index = this.putIndex;
        final int mask = this.mask;
        final int offset = (int) (mask & index);
        if (arr[offset] != null) {
            return false;
        }
        arr[offset] = e;  // use unsafe.xxx ? or AtomicReferenceArray#set?
        putIndex = (index+1); // use AtomicLong#increment?
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public E poll() {
        final long index = this.takeIndex;
        final int mask = this.mask;
        final int offset = (int) (mask & index);
        final E e = (E) arr[offset];
        if (e == null) {
            return null;
        }
        takeIndex = (index + 1); // use AtomicLong#increment?
        arr[offset] = null; // use unsafe.xxx ? or AtomicReferenceArray#set?
        return e;
    }

    // other methods
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current implementation is not thread-safe because there is no happens-before edge between producing and consuming an item. And there is no happens before edge between releasing a slot and acquiring a slot.

It has been quite some time I played with ringbuffers. But it should be sufficient to make take and put index 'synchronized' (e.g. an AtomicLong or a volatile long) and plain access to the array. That should create the happens-before edge between writing and reading an item. And typically the head and tail sequence of the ringbuffer are used to determine if there are items, no checking of null/not null within the array.

If you want to use something like this in production, I would suggest having a look at [JCTools](https://github.com/JCTools/JCTools).

JCTools is properly tested and typical performance bottlenecks like false sharing have been resolved. Apart from working with a full-blown volatile, which is relatively expensive, JCTools also offers more relaxed methods using release/acquire semantics which in most cases is good enough.

If it is for educational purposes, I would check out the JCTools code and also the following [java-ring-buffer](https://www.baeldung.com/java-ring-buffer).

Comment: Thanks pveentier!  As far as I understand it, the so-called thread unsafe is for example "i++". Two threads execute ```i++``` at the same time, which may eventually result in the value of i being 1 (the initial value is 0), which is a wrong result.  What you said ```no happens-before edge between producing and consuming an item.``` , what kind of problems will it cause?Will it produce any wrong behavior？

Comment: In your example, since the queue is SP/SC, there is no concurrent increment of the indices, so that isn't a problem (no race condition). If you modify the logic to determine space/items being available through the putIndex/takeIndex (please check the last link in my comment for an example), then you have 2 threads whereby 1 reads and the other one writes to the same location (e.g. the head/tail index). These actions are now conflicting and if these are not ordered by a happens before edge, you have a data race. Which means your program is not correctly synchronized and weird stuff can happen.

Comment: Weird stuff, in this case, is that you could for example return a null item from the array even though you checked that an item exists (based on the put/takeIndex). 

For a reasonable explanation about happens-before and data races, I would suggest checking out "Java Concurrency in Practice". But be warned, this is not an easy subject.

Comment: More weird stuff: a consumer could see a partly created object. Even though the producer first fully constructed the object and then writes it to the queue.